# How to point ssh to config file

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I just switched local systems so I have to get back into a server again using the ssh keys. I usually use `ssh david@server` to get in. But since I have switched to the new machine the only way I can get into the server is `ssh -i path/to/id_rsa_server david@0.0.0.0` which points to the private key on my machine.

Now I already have a config file set up in the `.ssh` folder which I copied over from the last machine. The file looks as such:

```
Host server
    Hostname 0.0.0.0
    User david
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_server
```

How do I get the ssh system to recognize the config file again?

Comment: What error/message do you get when you run `ssh david@server`? Also check if the permissions of your `~/.ssh/config` file are `600`.

Comment: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname server: Name or service not known` and permissions are set correctly

Comment: Unless you redacted the hostname, the error message seems to indicate that your config file has `Hostname clearpath` as value. That seems to be incorrect or am I missing something? 

Did you previous system use to map `clearpath` to the server IP address in `/etc/hosts` ? Otherwise I doubt it's resolvable.

Comment: No it did not. And on this system the `/etc/hosts` file is blank. I assumed the config file would handle the routing, etc but for some reason it isn't seeing the config file (I assume).

Comment: Oh you mean that `clearpath` is the name of the alias you gave to the ssh Host right? If that's the case I see what you mean now. 

Try to run your ssh command with more verbosity and force it to read the config file ie: `ssh -vvv -F ~/.ssh/config david@...` ?

Comment: If you think that my response answers the question you posed, please consider accepting it. It may not have solved your entire problem, but perhaps did answer the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally ssh will get its configuration from `~/.ssh/config` or globally from `/etc/ssh/config`.

To test:

1. Use `-v` flag with ssh to see if your config file is loaded. As comments suggest you can increase verbosity with additional `v`s like `-vvv`.

```
user@pc:~$ ssh -v server
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for server
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
```

2. Check owner and permissions on `.ssh/config`. Directory permissions should be 700, and check ownership. It is possible step 1 will give hints.

```
user@pc:~$ ls -ld --  .ssh*/
drwx------ 2 user user 4096 May 25 23:05 .ssh/
user@pc:~$ ls -la .ssh/config
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 39 May 25 23:05 .ssh/config
```

3. Launch `ssh` with `-F <path-to-config>` and see if there are issues.

```
user@pc:~$ ssh -v -F ~/.ssh/config
```

The items above should confirm permissions, paths, and file locations.

Comment: This helped very much. Thanks! I haven't solved it yet. However, I came to find that it was seeing the config file but the config file was not seeing the keys. give by: `debug1: identity file /home/david/.ssh/id_rsa_clearpath type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory`

Comment: Seems your config file points to the id file location but perhaps stored elsewhere. Happy it was helpful!

Comment: Those permissions (at least for `.ssh/config`) work. If there are no complaints using `-v` the permissions aren't the issue. If the command that you said works isn't `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_server david@0.0.0.0` that should give a clue too if your ssh config listed above is correct.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Other reasons that would result in this deadend situation:

- You are working on AWS and enabled UFW on Ubuntu for example.
- The server has an issue preventing SSH from being run.
  Having SSH enabled and properly working on the server is a good point of investigation to consider when local fixes don't wwork.